# Range does not filter my documents properly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am a kind of confused. I have a category_id in my elastic search document like:

```
[
 {
"id": "80029",
"categoryId": "43227",
"channelId": "54322",
"channelName": "xxxxx2222",
```

Now in elastic search when I search based on the range on category id as follows:

```
  {
 "query": {
   "range": {
    "category_id": {
    "lt": 1000032270000
    }
  }
}
 }
```

I get nothing back but it is obvious that 1000032270000 is greater than 43227 and I expecting to get the record back. More surprisingly whe I change the 1000032270000 to 9000032270000 I get the result. So what is my problem?how can I use filter my documents properly? (I am looking for sth like all documents grater that 4000 and less than 10000)

Comment: Can you show us the output of your mappings? GET /{YOUR_INDEX}/_mapping

I have a suspicion your field is mapped as a string, so "1000032270000" is greater than your value alphabetically, but less than "9000032270000" alphabetically

Comment: Do u mean this: {
  "_index": "stories",
  "_type": "String",
  "_id": "80061",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "80061",
    "category_id": "43227",
    "channel_id": "54322"
  }
}

Comment: I copied it from kibana

Comment: No, the mapping response. That is the query response.

Comment: @MikeMichaels I checked it the type is text "category_id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}

Comment: Right, so that is definitely your problem. Just need to make yourself a new index or reindex and have the long mapping applied for that field to sort as you'd expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is because of a string mapping. I will edit if this isn't the case.

Make sure you have the mapping for "category_id" set to be numeric. Try putting this as the mapping of that field (you will either need to re-create the index with the mapping before you ingest documents, or reindex to another index)

```
PUT {YOUR_INDEX}
{
  "mappings" :{
    "{YOUR_TYPE}":{
      "properties": {
        "category_id": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so for whatever field I insert into elastic search should I add type as well?

Comment: So this way if I have 10 fields I need to specify the type 10 times even if they are not index feilds?

Comment: I am using this to add my documents to elastic search. Can you help me how I can add mapping for my other fields?

Comment: If you need the field to be mapped to something other than what it is being mapped to dynamically, yes. In this case I'm assuming you're getting an dynamic mapping for string, even though you're expecting to treat it as as a number. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html

Comment: @HamedMinaee To answer your question about the other fields, we would need to know your intent for those. I'm going to guess you could use long for the categoryId and Id as well. You want to use a string (keyword or text) for the channel field.

Comment: Yes actually in my case I need a text search on text fields and also being able to have a range search on datetime fields and as you mentioned I will need category id as long

Comment: so do you think this is correct:  client.bulk({
        body:[{ index:  { _index: 'stories', _type: 'long', _id: id},"mappings": {
            "stories": {
                "properties": {
                    "category_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        } },createDynamoObject(record)]
    }, function (error, resp) {} I am adding mapping when I add the document but it still does not work

Comment: I am using this:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

Comment: @HamedMinaee You need to add your mapping before you index content. So https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html and then do your bulk indexing

Comment: So in the link you provided the tweet or users are the index? I am just a bit confused can  you explain what they are?

Comment: In the top example for the mapping, "twitter" is the index, "tweet" is the type that has property mapping of text for the field "message". 

The second "PUT" command in the top example on that link is applying a mapping for a field "name" of text on the user type.

The last one is just showing another way to put the mapping for the tweet. It's basically 3 examples doing similar things, twitter is the index for all of them, with user/tweet types and different text mapped fields

Comment: Just the last question for example instead of tweet in my case I do not know what to put. I understand index and also message as the field but still not how to deal with tweet. is it just sth that I can put randomly?

Comment: @HamedMinaee "tweet" would be the type within an index. https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-vs-type - The distinction between type/index can be pretty confusing. In the future I believe elastic is moving away from the use of "type" entirely. If you have SQL experience, I would say an "index" is an analogue to a table, and fields obviously being equivalent to fields/columns. As to where "type" fits in to an Elastic/SQL comparison, that's a bit more ambiguous. Personally, when dealing with data going to Elastic, I store everything under a single "type", avoiding that construction all together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you spent. I bugged you  a lot but you fixed my issues.

Comment: Glad it helped, hope you enjoy your time in the Elastic world